# Remove mutable objects from list

Tags: python-2.7

So I have the following class object:

```
class Bond(object):
    def __init__(self, Atom1=None, Atom2=None):
        self.atoms = [Atom1, Atom2]
```

where Atom1 and Atom2 are mutable objects.

and I have:

```
>>> first_bond
    Bond(Atom1, Atom2)
>>> second_bond
    Bond(Atom1, Atom3)
>>> third_bond
    Bond(Atom2, Atom1)
```

and also have:

```
>>> bonds
    [first_bond, second_bond, third_bond]
```

If you realize, the `first_bond` and `third_bond` are the same since one is the reverse of the other, this is:

```
>>> first_bond == third_bond[::-1]
    True
```

So my question is how can I implement a function or something that can filter only distinct objects, so that my final `bonds` is:

```
>>> bonds
    [first_bond, second_bond]
```

I have read that maybe using `__eq__` and `__hash__` method would be a solution, and then using `set(bonds)`. But since `Atoms` are mutable objects I don't know if this is kind of possible.

Comment: Do you *want* `Bond` instances to be mutable? That is, in your program, does it make sense for a given bond to have one or both of its endpoints change during the running of the program? If not, I'd simply make it immutable (the easiest way is probably to use `namedtuple` rather than writing your own version, but even that is not too hard) and go with `__hash__` and a `set`.

Comment: I have a question here: basically, what defines each bond is the identity of each composing atom, that is `Atom1` and `Atom2`. The problem is that each bond may vary during program execution, that is because `Atom1` or `Atom2` may change position in 3D-space. So my question would be, even if `Atoms` objects are mutable, may I create `Bond` class immutable?

Comment: The mutability in `set` context is understood as not changing properties which influence the `__hash__` and `__eq__` results. So you can define these functions to work only on atoms not caring about their positions, and all will be fine.